# Connect to Cloudera Cluster via Python

Tags: python, hadoop, export, hdfs, cloudera

I have a Cloudera cluster that's up and running.

I am currently writing a Python application which queries an API to get a response. I am writing this response to a text file within the application.

However, I would like to also export this text file to the cloudera cluster programmatically within the application. Is this possible?

Could you please point me to some references or sample codes to achieve this? Or simply your thoughts and suggestions on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to look at Spotify's Snakebite project, which give you a way to work with HDFS directly via Python. http://spotify.github.io/snakebite/

```
from snakebite.client import Client
client = Client("localhost", 54310, use_trash=False)
for x in client.ls(['/']):
    print x
```